# IDictionary`2 is not assignable from IDictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a property on my `ViewModel` that is of type `IDictionary<string, string>`. I am going through the list of properties on that `ViewModel`and using reflection to determine if it is a dictionary.

Currently I have:

```
if (typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(propDescriptor.PropertyType))
```

However, that is always false because `propDescriptor.PropertyType` is `` IDictionary`2 ``. Any ideas how I can get that to work? Also, why isn't that working?

---

I just changed my property to be IDictionary instead of IDictionary.

EDIT: Not sure where my generics went, but the second IDictionary in the sentence above has string, string.

Comment: Should it not then be if (typeof(IDictionary<string, string>).IsAssignableFrom(propDescriptor.PropertyType))

Comment: I need it to be generic, so I can't do that.

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765859/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-a-generic-type-is-built-from-a-specific-generic-t

Comment: Don't change the property type to the non-generic interface. Actually, don't use non-generic interfaces from .NET 1 when there are new generic interfaces that supersede them.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why it's not working is that the generic [`IDictionary<,>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) does not have the non-generic `IDictionary` as a base interface.

Maybe this is what you want:

```
var type = propDescriptor.PropertyType;
if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>))
{ // ...
```

**Edit:** The above code will only check if `type` is *declared* as `IDictionary<X, Y>` for some `X` and `Y`. If you also want to handle cases where `type` represents a class or struct that *implements* `IDictionary<X, Y>` (or even an interface derived from `IDictionary<X, Y>`), then try this:

```
Func<Type, bool> isGenericIDict =
  t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>);
var type = propDescriptor.PropertyType;
if (isGenericIDict(type) || type.GetInterfaces().Any(isGenericIDict))
{ // ..
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not `` IDictionary`2 ``.  It's the compiler-generated class name for a generic `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>`, which is not directly castable to an `IDictionary`.

Comment: The `2 is saying that the type has an arity of two, ie it has two type parameters..

Answer (score 1):

`` IDictionary`2 `` is not derived from `IDictionary` as can be seen in its definition:

```
public interface IDictionary<TKey, TValue> :
    ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>,
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>,
    IEnumerable
```

Therefore the generic `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is not castable to `IDictionary`.

Comment: I guess my question is, why is it doing IDictionary`2? Also, when I do this:
var dictionary = propDescriptor.GetValue(instance) as IDictionary; It works and gives me the value. I don't understand why that would work and the type check wouldn't.

Comment: You should differentiate between the `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` interface, which doesn't derive from `IDictionary` and the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class which does implement `IDictionary`.

Comment: That only works because `Dictionary<,>` implements `IDictionary` and `IDictionary<,>`, but `IDictionary<,>` does not implement `IDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

[IDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.aspx) is different from [IDictionary< T, K >](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx).

Use:

```
if (typeof(IDictionary<string, string>).IsAssignableFrom(propDescriptor.PropertyType))
```