# Find classes which inherits from a generic class using reflection

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, reflection, system.reflection

I need a way to filter my assemblies to get all classes that *inherits* from a generic class. I have found some posts but they are most like how to *check* the inheritence(e.g. [How to check if a class inherits another class without instantiating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8699053/1267304) and [Check if a class is derived from a generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/457676/1267304)). But these posts didn't helped me.

All my classes inherits from a specific one, called `BaseRepository<T>`, but some classes can inherit from `InterventionBaseRepository<T>`(which inherits from `BaseRepository<T>` as well). I need to find them. This is my code until now:

```
var q = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        where t.IsClass && 
             (t.Namespace != null &&
              t.Namespace.StartsWith("AgroWeb.Core.Data.Repository"))
        select t;
```

So, in short, the query above gets all my classes by *namespace* which I need to find among them those who inherits from `InterventionBaseRepository<T>`.

An example of a signature of a class which must be found:

```
public class CityRepository : InterventionBaseRepository<City>, ICityRepository
```

And the `InterventionBaseRepository` declaration:

```
public class InterventionBaseRepository<T> : BaseRepository<T>
    where T : Entity
```

I tried to use [`IsAssignableFrom()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.100).aspx) as said in those posts linked above in the query like this:

```
t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(InterventionBaseRepository<Entity>))
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt on `IsAssignableFrom`?

Comment: Did you get IsAssignableFrom() the right way around. i.e. abstraction.IsAssignableFrom(specialization)

Comment: @JamesLucas That was my thought too. It should work. OP needs to show his code.

Comment: @PatrickHofman check my update on the last paragraph.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown: It seems the types are the other way around.

Comment: @PatrickHofman like `typeof(InterventionBaseRepository<Entity>).IsAssignableFrom(t)` ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I guess so, see my answer.

Comment: I've edited your post to show names of the post you are linking... Please make sure to show code wrote based on `IsSubclassOfRawGeneric` so it is clear how it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are checking against Entity and not City. If you want to use covariant generic arguments then specify an interface for InterventionBaseRepository like this:

```
public interface IInterventionBaseRepository<out T> { }
```

Then have your InterventionBaseRepository implement it. Now Repo< City > can be treated as Repo< Entity >.

So:

```
public class InterventionBaseRepository<T> : BaseRepository<T>, IInterventionBaseRepository<T>
where T : Entity
{
}
```

Comment: Even if `City : Entity` which is the case(my bad I forgot mention it) ?

Answer (score 0):

from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5461399/891715):

```
            CityRepository value = new CityRepository();
            Type type = value.GetType();
            Type baseType = type.BaseType;
            if (baseType.IsGenericType)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(baseType.Name + " is generic type");

                Type itemType = baseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                Console.WriteLine("Generic argument: " + itemType.Name);

                Type genericType = baseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
                Console.WriteLine("Generic type: " + genericType.Name);

                Console.WriteLine("Generic base type: " + genericType.BaseType.Name);
            }

            if (type.IsAssignableToGenericType(typeof(BaseRepository<>)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("IsAssignableToGenericType: BaseRepository<>");
            }

        if (type.IsAssignableToGenericType(typeof(InterventionBaseRepository<>)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IsAssignableToGenericType: InterventionBaseRepository<>");
        }
```

and:

```
public static class Utils 
{
    public static bool IsAssignableToGenericType(this Type givenType, Type genericType)
    {
        var interfaceTypes = givenType.GetInterfaces();

        foreach (var it in interfaceTypes)
        {
            if (it.IsGenericType && it.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType)
                return true;
        }

        if (givenType.IsGenericType && givenType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType)
            return true;

        Type baseType = givenType.BaseType;
        if (baseType == null) return false;

        return IsAssignableToGenericType(baseType, genericType);
    }
}
```

output:

```
InterventionBaseRepository`1 is generic type
Generic argument: City
Generic type: InterventionBaseRepository`1
Generic base type: BaseRepository`1
IsAssignableToGenericType: BaseRepository<>
IsAssignableToGenericType: InterventionBaseRepository<>
```

Comment: Note that OP linked to very similar code and claim it did not work in they case... (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457676/check-if-a-class-is-derived-from-a-generic-class)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I checked my code and it works with mockup classes that represent the scenario given by the OP. It should work if he checks: var q = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        where t.IsClass && 
             (t.Namespace != null &&
              t.Namespace.StartsWith("AgroWeb.Core.Data.Repository")) && t.IsAssignableToGenericType(typeof(InterventionBaseRepository<>))
        select t;

Comment: Your code looks fine as there is really only one way to achieve what looks like goals of the question. The note is about OP already aware of the approach and somehow not not able to get it work to achieve actual, possibly slightly different goal.