# Determine if a variable is of a lazy type

Tags: c#, lazy-initialization, .net-4.7

Quick question - is there any 'prettier' way to determine if a variable was lazily initialized than:

```
var paramType = param.GetType();
if (paramType.FullName.Contains("System.Lazy")) 
{
    ...
}
```

I know it's not something really recommended to be checked, but there is a particular need to differentiate it.

Comment: Define "prettier". You could use something like `typeof(Lazy<>).IsAssignableFrom(param.GetType())`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461295/using-isassignablefrom-with-open-generic-types

Comment: @CodeCaster That returns false

Comment: @Haytam I know, therefore I link to a question that properly handles open generic types.

Comment: Can you say more about your particular need? there may be a better way to solve the real problem. This smells like an xy problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (paramType.IsGenericType && paramType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Lazy<>))
```

It should return `true` if `param` is a `Lazy<T>` (and `paramType` is `param.GetType()`).

Answer (score 1):

You could compare the generic definition of your param instead:

```cs
Lazy<int> test = new Lazy<int>();
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Lazy<>) == test.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition());
```

You might want to hold on to the `typeof(Lazy<>)` in a static variable.

Answer (score 0):

The two edge cases here are when the type is not a constructed generic type, and when the type is subtype of of Lazy.  So something like

```
typeof(Lazy<>).IsAssignableFrom(paramType.IsConstructedGenericType?paramType.GetGenericTypeDefinition():null);
```