# How do I know if the PropertyInfo is of ICollect<> type - Reflection and GenericType

Tags: c#, reflection

```
class Abc {
    public Mycollection<Person> Persons { get;set; }
}

class MyCollection<T> : ICollect<T> { ... }
```

I'm using reflection, getting the PropertyInfo of ABC.Persons.

I want to know if the PropertyInfo is of ICollect<> type - how do I do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want to know if the Property (Persons) is ICollect<> ?

Comment: @DennyFerrassoli...that's exactly I wanna know .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems similar to: [How To Detect If Type is Another Generic Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74616/how-to-detect-if-type-is-another-generic-type)

```
public static bool IsAssignableToGenericType(Type givenType, Type genericType) {
var interfaceTypes = givenType.GetInterfaces();

foreach (var it in interfaceTypes)
    if (it.IsGenericType)
        if (it.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType) return true;

Type baseType = givenType.BaseType;
if (baseType == null) return false;

return baseType.IsGenericType &&
    baseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType ||
    IsAssignableToGenericType(baseType, genericType);
```

}