# Determine if a property is a kind of array by reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I determine if a property is a kind of array.

Example:

```
public bool IsPropertyAnArray(PropertyInfo property)
{
    // return true if type is IList<T>, IEnumerable<T>, ObservableCollection<T>, etc...
}
```

Comment: So you mean, if the property is a collection?  Things that match your comment are not arrays.

Comment: You probably meant `IEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerator`?

Comment: @Ben: Well, arrays match his criteria (IList<T> and IEnumerable<T>), but not all things that match his criteria are arrays. :)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You appear to be asking two different questions: whether a type is an array (e.g. `string[]`) or any collection type.

For the former, simply check `property.PropertyType.IsArray`.

For the latter, you have to decide what is the minimum criteria you want a type to conform to. For example, you could check for the non-generic `IEnumerable` by using `typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType)`. You can also use this for generic interfaces if you know the actual type of T, e.g. `typeof(IEnumerable<int>).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType)`.

Checking for the generic `IEnumerable<T>` or any other generic interface without knowing the value of T can be done by checking if `property.PropertyType.GetInterface(typeof(IEnumerable<>).FullName)` is not `null`. Note that I didn't specify any type for `T` in that code. You can do the same for `IList<T>` or any other type you're interested in.

For example you could use the following if you want to check for the generic `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public bool IsPropertyACollection(PropertyInfo property) 
{ 
    return property.PropertyType.GetInterface(typeof(IEnumerable<>).FullName) != null;
}
```

Arrays also implement IEnumerable, so they will also return `true` from that method.

Comment: This implementation would miss "old school collections", inherited from .Net 1 and which implements IEnumerable but not the generic version IEnumerable<T>.
They are less and less used, but some API expects them, and they are really a pain.

Comment: @Falanwe: Then use the first method I mentioned, which does check for the non-generic IEnumerable. It really depends on his requirements which is best.

Comment: I try your method with an property that is a string and the method return true... Do you know why?

Comment: @Melursus: the `String` class implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so it qualifies as a collection under these criteria. You either need to filter it out specifically, or check for a more restrictive interface (e.g. `ICollection<T>` or `IList<T>`).

Comment: Any type that implements generic `IEnumerable<>` will also be a non-generic `IEnumerable`, of course.

Comment: Please note that type string is regarded as IEnumerable<char> which means it will be included in this check. If you don't want that you can just extend the criteria slightly: property.PropertyType.GetInterface(typeof(IEnumerable<>).FullName) != null && property.PropertyType != typeof(string)

Comment: This is a concise solution if your coding against the full .NET Framework.  But note that [`Type.GetInterface`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayfa0fcd.aspx) isn't available in PCLs, etc..  So you may need to use [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1075059).

Answer (score 22):

Excluding `String` class as it qualifies as a collection because it implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

```
public bool IsPropertyACollection(this PropertyInfo property)
{
    return (!typeof(String).Equals(property.PropertyType) && 
        typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType));
}
```

Comment: typeof(String) was the check I was missing

Answer (score 19):

If you want to know if the property is an array, it's actually very easy:

```
property.PropertyType.IsArray;
```

**edit**

If you want to know if it's a type that implements IEnumerable, as do all "collection types", it's not very complicated either:

```
return property.PropertyType.GetInterface("IEnumerable") != null;
```

Comment: I am not sure if that's what OP really wanted (but I admit naming is a bit misleading). Custom type implementing `IList<T>` will return false from this property.

Comment: indeed, I misread the question initially. I edited my answer to include any IEnumerable

Comment: @Falanwe: `IsSubclassOf` doesn't work for interfaces, only base classes.

Comment: @Falanwe: I can't read French, but the English version says "The IsSubclassOf method **cannot** be used to determine whether an interface derives from another interface, or whether a class implements an interface" (emphases mine).

Comment: @Sven: you're right, I read the documentation too quickly. I edited my answer

Answer (score 3):

```
    public static bool IsGenericEnumerable(Type type)
    {
        return type.IsGenericType && 
            type.GetInterfaces().Any(
            ti => (ti == typeof (IEnumerable<>) || ti.Name == "IEnumerable"));
    }

    public static bool IsEnumerable(Type type)
    {
        return IsGenericEnumerable(type) || type.IsArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the following is not working,

```
return property.PropertyType.GetInterface(typeof(ICollection<>).FullName) != null;
```

Following was working,

```
typeof(ICollection<>).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
```

This is shortcut way to check `ICollection<IInterface>`or`ICollection<BaseClassInTree>`

```
var property = request as PropertyInfo;

property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && (typeof(ICollection<>).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())) && typeof().IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0])
```