# How to best check for List type on reflection and iterate over its members

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm using reflection to get all properties of a specific object and iterate over them.

I'm calling these properties `props`.

When those are non-List objects, this all works fine.

I need a way to know when a prop I'm iterating over is a list (I saw there is a `prop.PropertyType.IsArray` for instance, but not one for list).

I saw here [Determine if a property is a kind of array by reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434825/determine-if-a-property-is-a-kind-of-array-by-reflection) that they suggested to use:

`property.PropertyType.GetInterface(typeof(IEnumerable<>).FullName) != null`

But this is not good enough for me since `string` implements that as well.

(Right now I'm checking that `prop.Namespace` contains "collection" in it, obviously looking for a better way).

After I've done that, I have a working assumption that the List will be a List of a complex object. (but could be one of several complex ojects so I don't know which)

The harder part is that I need to iterate over those objects and get ***their*** members as well, but have failed to do so.

So if I have `List<TestObject>` as my `prop` I need to have a `foreach (TestObject testObj in prop)` somehow (in concept).

Don't have a reasonable attempt to show here, since I haven't yet figured out a way  to treat `prop` as a List of my complex object and iterate over it.

EDIT: I've managed to get the value with `prop.GetValue(reflectedObject)` but I have to cast that to `List<MyComplexObject>`

Answer (score 2):

I think looking into this code sample can help.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<int> Subordinates { get; set; }
}
```

Use MyClass:

```
var myClass = new MyClass
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "My Name",
    Subordinates = new List<int> { 2, 5, 8 }
};

var props = myClass.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var info in props)
{
    var type = info.PropertyType;

    if (type.IsGenericType && (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)))
    {
        foreach (var listitem in info.GetValue(myClass, null) as IEnumerable)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Item: " + listitem.ToString());
        }

        continue;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(info.GetValue(myClass, null));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that working with the `IEnumerable<>` interface is actually the way forward. Do you have some sort of a base type for your objects? If yes, then you can work around the issue with `string` be looking for collections of objects that extend the base type. If no, then you can treat strings as a special case before you check for the `IEnumerable<>` interface.