# How to determine if a type is a type of collection?

Tags: c#, collections, types, refactoring

I am trying to determine if a runtime type is some sort of collection type. What I have below works, but it seems strange that I have to name the types that I believe to be collection types in an array like I have done.

In the code below, the reason for the generic logic is because, in my app, I expect all collections to be generic.

```
bool IsCollectionType(Type type)
{
    if (!type.GetGenericArguments().Any())
        return false;

    Type genericTypeDefinition = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    var collectionTypes = new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<>), typeof(ICollection<>), typeof(IList<>), typeof(List<>) };
    return collectionTypes.Any(x => x.IsAssignableFrom(genericTypeDefinition));
}
```

How would I refactor this code to be smarter or simpler?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that you usually don't want to consider `string` as a collection of `char`s, even though it implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Really all of these types inherit [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx). You can check only for it:

```
bool IsEnumerableType(Type type)
{
    return (type.GetInterface(nameof(IEnumerable)) != null);
}
```

or if you really need to check for `ICollection`:

```
bool IsCollectionType(Type type)
{
    return (type.GetInterface(nameof(ICollection)) != null);
}
```

Look at "Syntax" part:

- [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)
- [`IList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx)
- [`ICollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.collections.icollection.aspx)

If you need to exclude strings (which are essentially an IEnumerable<char>), use the following function:

```
bool IsEnumerableType(Type type)
{
    return (type.Name != nameof(String) 
        && type.GetInterface(nameof(IEnumerable)) != null);
}
```

Comment: Haha. It really was THAT simple. For some reason I thought that wouldn't work and I didn't try it.

Comment: Inheritance hierarchy in the doc doesn't tell you implemented interfaces. But looking at the Syntax section will.

Comment: @svick: What about
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, 
 IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
?

Comment: @Ruben, that's exactly what I meant, but that's not in the Inheritance Hierarchy section.

Comment: I tend to over think simple problems as well ;)

Comment: Checking `IEnumerable` has the problem of incorrectly interpreting `string` as a collection. This is not desirable most of the time.

Comment: Didn't work for me at all. `ICollection<CPerson>` returned `null` on `type.GetInterface("ICollection")` and on `type.GetInterface("System.Collections.Generic.ICollection")`

Comment: @MohammadDehghan This is why you should use `nameof(ICollection)` instead.

Comment: Make sure you use `nameof(System.Collections.IEnumerable)`, in my case I have a reference to `using System.Collections.Generic;` and it was a confusion with `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Be careful with this, as string also implements IEnumerable

Comment: Using nameof will enforce you to provide the generic type argument too, instead you can use .GetInterface("IEnumerable")

Comment: This returns true for String type :O

Comment: @MohaDehghan but string IS a collection. It implements the interface, so there. We come across the need to rigorously define "collection".

Answer (score 4):

You can use this helper method to check if a type implements an open generic interface. In your case you can use `DoesTypeSupportInterface(type, typeof(Collection<>))`

```
public static bool DoesTypeSupportInterface(Type type,Type inter)
{
    if(inter.IsAssignableFrom(type))
        return true;
    if(type.GetInterfaces().Any(i=>i. IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition()==inter))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Or you can simply check for the non generic `IEnumerable`. All collection interfaces inherit from it. But I wouldn't call any type that implements `IEnumerable` a collection.

Comment: Or use the solution [found here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1075059/122781) which works for generic types in addition to generic interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq, search for an interface name like

```
yourobject.GetType().GetInterfaces().Where(s => s.Name == "IEnumerable")
```

If this has values is a instance of `IEnumerable`.

Comment: So does string leading to a false positive

Comment: String is a character collection, so it's not a false positive. Maybe it's not what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

This solution will take care of `ICollection` and `ICollection<T>`.

```cs
    static bool IsCollectionType(Type type)
    {
        return type.GetInterfaces().Any(s => s.Namespace == "System.Collections.Generic" && (s.Name == "ICollection" || s.Name.StartsWith("ICollection`")));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me.

```
private static bool IsCollectionType(Type type)
{
    return type.GetInterfaces().Any(s => s.Namespace == "System.Collections.Generic" && (s.Name == "IEnumerable" || s.Name.StartsWith("IEnumerable`")));
}
```