# How can I know both class are from same Generic class

Tags: c#, reflection, generic-programming

Here is sample code. How can I know both Foo and Bar are from same class Base<>?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = typeof(Foo).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Base<,>));
        var bar = typeof(Bar).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Base<,>));
    }
}

public abstract class Base<TInput, TOutput>
{
    public abstract TOutput Run(TInput input);
}


public class Foo : Base<int, string>
{
    public override string Run(int input)
    {
        return input.ToString();
    }
}

public class Bar : Base<string, string>
{
    public override string Run(string input)
    {
        return input.Replace(".", "").ToString();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: your compilation errors can be solved by  var foo = typeof(Foo).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Base<int, string>));
var bar = typeof(Bar).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Base<string, string>));

Comment: Just to make sure you're solving the problem the right way, what do you intend to _do_ if they both inherit from some specific type of that generic class?

Comment: Sorry buddies, just updated question.

Comment: It's already been answered here I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74616/how-to-detect-if-type-is-another-generic-type/1075059#1075059

Comment: @StewartRitchie Thanks, buddy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your code compile you will need to change `Base<>` to `Base<,>` because it has two type parameters. Still `IsAssignableFrom` should not work cause, maybe something like this will work for you:

```
var foo = typeof(Foo).BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == (typeof(Base<,>));
var bar = typeof(Bar).BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == (typeof(Base<,>));
```

?

Comment: @Dongdong you missed the `.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == (typeof(Base<,>))` part =)

Comment: @Dongdong glad it helped! But beware, it will work only for this hierarchy, if you introduce more levels of inheritance you will need to make more complicated checks.

Comment: yes, you are right, just tried, how to resolve hierarchy issue? can you give more code for hierarchy? should I start a new question for it?

Comment: @Dongdong See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74616/how-to-detect-if-type-is-another-generic-type/1075059#1075059) as  Stewart Ritchie suggested, so you basically need to check in cycle/via recursion for `BaseType` and check it against being generic and equal to searched type.